# Getting database connection fail issue, after site migration to php 5.6 and mysql 5.6

Tags: php, mysql

Guys getting a database error, after website migration.

```
<?php
```

final class MySQL {
    private $connection;

```
public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
    if (!$this->connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)) {
        exit('Error: Could not make a database connection using ' . $username . '@' . $hostname);
    }


if (!mysql_select_db($database, $this->connection)) {
        exit('Error: Could not connect to database ' . $database);
    }

    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $this->connection);
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $this->connection);
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION=utf8", $this->connection);
    mysql_query("SET SQL_MODE = ''", $this->connection);
}



public function query($sql) {
    $resource = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
```

Comment: What error you receive? But it doesn't matter as you probably want to re-factor your code from using PHP mysql API to mysqli or PDO. It is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development, as it was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and was removed in PHP 7.

Comment: @hcheung  If i replace all mysql to mysqli, so it will work?